# Drawing PNG image on canvas: performance issue

Tags: android, performance, png, android-canvas

Is there any other way to draw .png image on canvas than BitmapFactory.decodeResource()? My problem is that when you create bitmap from 10kB image, you still get a bitmap sized depending on screen width and height. I need to display up to 16 images on the screen at one time, and on hi-res screen (f.e., 1280 x 720) it requires plenty of memory, and I have lags even on my HTC One X (when I try, f.e., to move or scale images).
So is there any other way to display .png images on canvas, or maybe some other solutions to improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your performance in several ways:

- Android use [Blit blit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit)(dirty rects) technique with views, so if your screen have several png images, try spliting them in views and make sure that they are not touching each other, then you will get the dirty rect performance bonus.
- If you have several views above each other then you can use a buffer bitmap to draw them there and when update is needed, just draw your buffer. This is very useful when you have few updates to your buffer.
- For android versions 2.2 and below you can use [Paint.setFilterBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap%28boolean%29) to false, to avoid filtering scaled images, this have a huge effect on performace, how ever scaled images looks bad. And when hardware acceleration is turned on(default from android 4.0) this flag is set to true and you cannot change it.
- Cutting images: You can split your image in to several parts to reduce the png image size and make the rest of it jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky workaround:

You can try to create a Bitmap with size of the screen.

Draw the 16 Bitmaps on that Bitmap using Canvas.

Display that big Bitmap instead of 16 small ones.